# OpenCL lossless video compression

Tags: opencv, opencl, gpu, video-encoding, lossless-compression

I am looking for a lossless video compression in OpenCL. It has to be lossless as it is a project requirement. Found a few lossless algorithm written in OpenCV and ffmpeg but none of them supports OpenCL encoding/decoding. I am using Apple computers and they come with ATI graphics card which does not support CUDA.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use x264, which already has OpenCL support, and use a CRF of 0 (lossless). I know, looks like mpeg4 is always lossy but turns out it has also a lossless mode, that most of the times works better than other lossless codecs.

```
avconv -i input -c:v libx264 -preset slow --opencl -crf 0 -c:a copy outvideo.mp4
```

OpenCL in x264 is marginally faster than plain CPU so it is not widely used. EDIT: In my system my libx264 does not accept `--opencl`, but I think never versions do accept that parameter. Maybe you will need a binary executable "x264" since libx264 may not expose all the underlying functionality.

Comment: Our application is very CPU intensive, as long as I can off load some processing to GPU that would be great. I'll give your answer try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Oh, ok in that case it can help. x264 will load balance, so it is probably a good practice to keep the x264 to a single CPU core + GPU, to use the most of the GPU device.

Comment: I want to convert png files to video, ffmpeg has the same problem does not accept --opencl with libx264. Do you know how to do that with x264?

Comment: You have here the x264 binaries http://download.videolan.org/pub/x264/binaries/ In order to load pngs you will need to provide the input as "%05d.png" for pngs like 00001.png ....

Comment: What? The actual command is -x264-params opencl=true. Wow, just wow.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will find anything that already exists implemented in OpenCL for this lossless video compression task. Your best bet would be to take something that already exists and then try to adapt that, but the basic approach of OpenCL is splitting compute tasks up into different threads that operate on small chunks of memory. You might take a look at [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) as a starting point.